# Getting error trying to count occurences of each letter from file

Tags: python, typeerror, traceback

I am trying to create a program which counts the occurrences of each letter from text pulled from another file. I haven't got too far with it yet, I just ran my first test for letter A and am not able to go further. This was my first attempt at assigning multiple variables to a single value, is this where my error occurred? Here is my code, go easy, I'm not very good at this stuff, but I'm trying to learn.

```
    file = open('words.txt', 'r')
    A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z = 0

    def LetterA():
        for line in file:
            words = line.split()
            for i in words:
                for letter in i:
                    if(letter == a) or (letter == A):
                        A = A + 1
        return A
    LetterA()

    print(A)
```

Here is my error print out:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:/Python/twentysecondprogram.py", line 2, in <module>
        A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z = 0
    TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new at python, so don't blame me if I'm wrong :))

1. I think your variable is out of scope.

Try this.

```
    def letter_A():
    letterA = 0
    for line in file:
        words = line.split()
        for i in words:
            for letter in i:
                if(letter == 'a') or (letter == 'A'):
                    letterA += 1
    print(letterA)


letter_A()
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to learn by yourself, step by step.
So I don't give you a ready solution but I correct the two errors:

> A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z = [0] * 26
>
> if letter == 'a' or letter == 'A':

And you can simplify the first two for- loops in one:

```
for line in file:
    for letter in line:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

with open('words.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

for letter in letters:
    occurences = ''.join(lines).count(letter)
    print(letter + ": " + str(occurences))
```

This is the complete code for you problem. You don't have to make a function for counting every single letter.

Comment: Ehm it works but it isn't a good example to join(lines) inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Even with [Massimo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61564383/python-error-trying-to-count-occurences-of-each-letter-from-file/61564511#61564511) corrections, you would be unable to assign a count to a global variable, (A-Z defined outside the function). There is a way to do this however, just declare `global A` inside the function. But you probably wouldn't want this for all 26 letters of the alphabet.

There is a handy function in [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) called [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which will get the count of letters in a string (or any body of text).

Counter can get the count of any iterable.

It could be used this way:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('anna.book', 'r') as f:
    c = Counter(f.read().lower())

for vowel in ('a','e','i','o','u'):
    print(vowel, c[vowel])
```

It counts the vowels in this file (which have all been converted to lower case (here `c = Counter(f.read().lower())`).

```
a 11745
e 17696
i 10392
o 10957
u 3934
```

**Update:**

Seeing your need not to use any imported library, the following could be used:

```
def letter_count(text,letter):
    return text.count(letter)

letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
           'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

with open('anna.book', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read().lower()

for letter in letters:
    counts = letter_count(text, letter)
    print(letter, counts)
```

Although, there is no real need for a function to count the letters:

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
           'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

with open('anna.book', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read().lower()

for letter in letters:
    counts = text.count(letter)
    print(letter, counts)
```

You could also use a dictionary to keep count of the letters seen

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
           'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

with open('anna.book', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read().lower()

count = dict()

for letter in text:
    if letter in count:
        count[letter] += 1
    else:
        # if this is the first time this letter is seen
        count[letter] = 1

for letter in letters:
    print(letter, count[letter])
```

**Update2:**

Just realized that I'm not following your method. Here it is but you'll notice there is only 1 function that takes a letter as an argument instead of a different function for each of the 26 letters.

```
file = open('anna.book', 'r')
LINES = file.readlines()
file.close()

def letter_counter(char):
    letter_cnt = 0
    for line in LINES:
        for letter in line:
            if letter.lower() == char.lower():
                letter_cnt += 1

    return letter_cnt

for vowel in ('a','e','i','o','u'):
    print(vowel, letter_counter(vowel))
```

Here `LINES` is a global list of all the lines in the file, read as `LINES = file.readlines()`. That way, the program can read the lines for more than 1 letter instead of reading through the file for the first letter.

When I was in school, we had to do a word search puzzle where the word could be found in 1 of eight directions, (N, NE, E, SE, S, ...) and I created a function for each of the 8 directions.

However, now I found it better to create just one function and pass the direction as a parameter to the function and inside the function, to travel in the passed direction.

Hope this example following your approach is helpful. (Just saying that it isn't necessary to create 26 functions when one will do)

Comment: This is for a class I am taking so I cannot use imports, trying to learn what those imports actually do kinda thing. thank you very much though

Comment: @Dmart425 I've added some possible solutions that might be helpful.

Comment: @Dmart425 I've added a suggested solution which follows your approach.

Answer (score 0):

So this is where I'm at right now... I did one of these for every letter... it only brings back the results for A. I tried adding a call to each of these at the end and it only performs the first one. It did bring back the correct number for A, so I have that going for me.

```
file = open('words.txt', 'r')
def letter_A():
    letterA = 0
    for line in file:
        words = line.split()
        for i in words:
            for letter in i:
                if(letter == 'a') or (letter == 'A'):
                    letterA += 1
    if letterA >= 1:
        print('A:', letterA)

def letter_B():
    letterB = 0
    for line in file:
        words = line.split()
        for i in words:
            for letter in i:
                if(letter == 'b') or (letter == 'B'):
                    letterB += 1
    if letterB >= 1:
        print('B:', letterB)
```

Comment: It will only work for the firsl letter, (A), because once you've read the file all the way through, the next letter, (B), won't read because the file was opened and read. You could fix that by reading the file into an array of lines, `for line in lines:` where `lines` is the array you've read your file into.